# Not able to get other(other than signed in user) Linkedin Members Profile basic data from their email ID using Linkedin API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I want to get the basic profile details of all the Linkedin Members based on their mail ID, but I am not able to get the relevant information in their docs.

I tried to create an app, initialized the JavaScript SDK, authenticated and tried to access the basic_profile data, but can fetch only the Signed in user basic profile data and not the other Linkedin Member's basic profile data :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    onLoad:    authorize
    authorize: true
</script>

<script>
function authorize(){
    console.log("success");

    IN.User.authorize(data);
}

function data(){

    IN.API.Profile("me").result(ShowProfileData);// Can I use this call to

// get other people details by replacing "me" with the other person mail id.
}

function ShowProfileData(profiles) {
    var member = profiles.values[0];
    var id=member.id;
    var firstName=member.firstName; 
    var lastName=member.lastName; 
    var photo=member.pictureUrl; 
    var headline=member.headline; 

    console.log(firstName + lastName + photo);

    //use information captured above
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

And that is like that by design. You will need to be a partner and have your application approved to be able to access detailed data beyond the signed user.

Edit to respond to comment:
Check https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api#me

Entries such as patents, publications, will have other ids.

Notice that you will not be able to get a list of all user id's in LinkedIn, but you can the one for the users that grant the auth and the ones in their profiles.

Comment: Thanks. We raised a query on the partner portal.

Comment: What was their answer?

Comment: They will revert us in 15 days, do upvote the question so other can come to know.

Comment: They give link to the https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api#people but we don't know about how to get the user id ?